# Mail returns false

Tags: php

I'm currently using a custom made library at my job. Until just rencently the library was working perfectly. It apparently return false since about today.

The library itself it basically a wrapper around the function mail. It builds the "boundaries" parts and everything.

Since the class is quite big enough I wont post it here ... but I'm wondering, what are the reasons in theory of why mail would return false?

- SMTP is set in PHP.ini
- Sender is set in headers
- Sender is int the form of: `sender<sender@email.com`>
- Everything is sent correctly (body+headers+subject)
- Assume that mail( ) works correctly on the website but on this specific page it just doesn't. I know it must be comming from me but would be fun to have somewhere to start looking for.
- Oh and yeah the library is undocumented.

[edit]
Just found a smaller function and still doesn't work, I'll print it out then:

```
function send_html($from, $email, $subject = "AUCUN", $message, $cc = "", $bcc ="", $priotity = "3") {
    $headers = "";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    if (strpos($from, "ourwebsite.com") != false || strpos($from, "rencontresportive.com") != "") {
        $headers .= "From: Ourwebsite.com <" . $from . ">\r\n";
    } else {
        $headers .= "From: " . $from . " <" . $from . ">\r\n";
    }

    $headers .= "X-Sender: <" . $from . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: " . $priotity . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: <admin@ourwebsite.com>\r\n";

    if ($cc != "") {
        $headers .= "cc:" . $cc . "\r\n";
    }
    if ($bcc != "") {
        $headers .= "bcc:" . $bcc . "\r\n";
    }
        if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I called it with :

```
send_html(contact@ourwebsite.com, me@me.com, utf8_decode("the subject"), "<h1>test</h1>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class is only a wrapper around the function mail, I would try printing to a file the parameters used when calling the mail function

Answer (score 19):

I just had the same problem.
After a php upgrade, the mail function always returns false.

I used this little snippet to check it out:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo 'I am : ' . `whoami`;
$result = mail('myaddress@mydomain.com','Testing 1 2 3','This is a test.');
echo '<hr>Result was: ' . ( $result === FALSE ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE') . $result;
echo '<hr>';
echo phpinfo();
```

The solution was setting a value in my php.ini for 'sendmail_from' and 'sendmail_path'.
The correct values in my case were:

```
sendmail_from = "no-reply@mydomain.net"
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

(I'm using CentOS 5.3 w/ Zend Server CE.)

You could use ini_set() to set the value of 'sendmail_from', but the 'sendmail_path' var must be setup in your php.ini or http.conf.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem , mail function always returns false even if the email is received successfully.

I found in php configuration file php.ini,
I had set up

```
; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f "care@mydomain.com"
```

I have changed it to below

```
; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f care@mydomain.com
```

As per this sendmail_from is for win32 , so in *unix OS we need to set the value as shown in sendmail_path variable.

Regards
Minesh

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', $from);
```

If you could show us the code it would be easier to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the address you are trying to send it to, the server that handles it is rejecting the mail.

There are too many variables involved to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is to check the error log.

For apache and Ubuntu (for example), the error log is located under `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

This can give you a clue about what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Is your assumption that the mail() function works one you have tested?  I would check to make sure that the library isn't just passing a failure of the mail() function up.

If you have tested the assumption, I would review the return statements from the library and see if I could find what would cause a false value.  That's often reasonably possible even in undocumented code.

Comment: It's mail itself that is returning false. I made sure to verify the return value of mail.

Answer (score 0):

For me it does neither; it doesn’t send and returns false!
here is my code;

```
<?php
function send_email($para, $assunto, $msg){
    $to      = $para;
    $subject = $assunto;

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= str_replace("\\r\\n","<br/>",$msg);
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    $headers = 'From: email@realemail.com' . "PHP_EOL";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: email@realemail.com' . "PHP_EOL";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "PHP_EOL";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "PHP_EOL";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "PHP_EOL";

    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

$to_email = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'TITLE';
$message = 'message';

if (send_email($to_email, $subject, $message)){
  echo "SUCCESS: <br>";
}
else { echo "FAIL :/ <br>";}
echo "$message"; //output a message
echo "<br>";
?>
```