# Fadeout Email Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to have a bootstrap contact form fade out on submit.

I am working with code I have found (which I've slightly modified to suit my needs), and I am having trouble with its implementation. I'm fairly new and I seem to have gotten quite stuck.

Here is the JS:

```
$('contactUs').on('submit', function mailMe(form) {
    form.preventDefault(); //Prevents default submit
    var form = $(this); 
    var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
    var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
    $('#loader', form).html('<img src="http://domain.com/test/images/loading.gif" /> Please Wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://domain.com/test/process.php', // Your form script
        data: post_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                form.html(msg).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the Form:

```
<form name="contactUs" onSubmit="return mailMe(this.form)" >
    <div class="inputWrap">
        <div class="fname">
            <input class="myInput miLeft" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="femail">
            <input class="myInput miRight" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="taWrap">
            <textarea class="myTa" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btns btn-3 btn-3g btnsx">Send</button>
</form>
```

And here is the process.php:

```
<?php

/* Configuration */
$subject = 'New Customer Email'; // Set email subject line here
$mailto  = 'myemail@me.com'; // Email address to send form submission to
/* END Configuration */

$name           = $_POST['name'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$messageContent      = $_POST['messageContent'];
$timestamp = date("F jS Y, h:iA.", time());

// HTML for email to send submission details
$body = "
<br>
<p>The following information was submitted through the contact form on your website:</p>
<p><b>Name</b>: $name<br>
<b>Email</b>: $email<br>
<b>Message</b>: $messageContent<br>
<p>This form was submitted on <b>$timestamp</b></p>
";

// Success Message
$success = "
<div class=\"row-fluid\">
    <div class=\"span12\">
        <h3>Submission successful</h3>
        <p>Thank you for taking the time to contact Shaz Construction & Design. A representative will be in contact with you shortly. If you need immediate assistance or would like to speak to someone now, please feel free to contact us directly at <strong>(415) 382-8442</strong>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
";

$headers = "From: $name <$email> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>$body</body></html>";

if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "$success"; // success
} else {
    echo 'Form submission failed. Please try again...'; // failure
}

?>
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen at all, which is making me realize that I'm missing something big here. The page just reloads. The form is [here](http://yasharsahaleh.com/test/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few small things you are missing:

- Your jQuery selector for the form is incorrect - give your form an ID attribute of `contactUs`, and then use the selector `$('form#contactUs')`. Get rid of the name attribute on the form.
- Your button element needs to be of type submit - your button currently does nothing.
- You don't need the onSubmit attribute, you are already binding your form to an event in the JS.
- Your input tags currently do not have any name elements on them - they are required - see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
- You try to access an attribute on the form that does not exist (action), but you don't use it, so just remove that line.
- Use `return false` rather than preventDefault in your event handler (I couldn't get preventDefault to work. That might just be me though!)
- I can't tell this because of the context of your code, but ensure that your JS is within a `$('document').ready(function() { ... }` block.

I think that your JS and HTML should be:

**JS**

```
$('form#contactUs').on('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this); 
    var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
    $('#loader').html('<img src="http://yasharsahaleh.com/test/images/loading.gif" /> Please Wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://yasharsahaleh.com/test/process.php', // Your form script
        data: post_data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#loader').html('');

            // We know this is the form that needs fading in/out
            $('form#contactUs').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $('form#contactUs').html(msg).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactUs">
    <div class="inputWrap">
        <div class="fname">
            <input name="name" class="myInput miLeft" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="femail">
            <input name="email" class="myInput miRight" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="taWrap">
            <textarea name="messageContent" class="myTa" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btns btn-3 btn-3g btnsx">Send</button>
</form>
```

I made a small JSFiddle to illustrate most of this (taking out the AJAX part): http://jsfiddle.net/dualspiral/2rXas/1/

The PHP needs changing slightly, you are not actually printing out the variable contents. The body variable shoud actually be assigned:

```
$body = "
    <br>
    <p>The following information was submitted through the contact form on your website:</p>
    <p><b>Name</b>: " . $name . "<br>
    <b>Email</b>: " . $email . "<br>
    <b>Message</b>: " . $messageContent . "<br>
    <p>This form was submitted on <b>" . $timestamp . "</b></p>
";
```

and the last lines should read:

```
$headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . "> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . " \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>" . $body . "</body></html>";

if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo $success; // success
} else {
    echo 'Form submission failed. Please try again...'; // failure
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I seem to have gotten it all there, however my form seems to fail on every submit (regardless of if the data is valid or not). I have the [form setup here](http://yasharsahaleh.com/test/index.html)

Comment: You are very welcome. As for your form, your mail function is returning false. I don't know too much about it, though I suspect there is the possibility that your host restricts use of the function, or that it is misconfigured. Apart from pointing you at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, or [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786221/mail-returns-false), I can't really help further. Best of luck!