# Sending mails from php script

Tags: php, apache, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I am trying to test a php script locally on ubuntu and i am using lamp server for this. When i try to run the php script to send mails, the mail function always returns false . i am attaching the snippet of the code.

```html
 $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string("ram")."\n";

 
// create email headers
    echo $email;

  $email_to = "kk@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "subject";
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message)){echo "success";}
else{
 echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: try removing the `echo $email;` before the `mail` function

Comment: There are some good suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786221/mail-returns-false

Comment: You can try to get some more info about the failure by dumping `error_get_last()['message'];` right after calling the function.

Comment: dumping is not working. Not getting any info from it and commenting out echo doesnt work either

Comment: where is defined your `clean_string` function?

Comment: in the file itself,it works..i have checked it