# PHP mail() function is returning false but email was received successfully

Tags: php, email

I am returning false when using the php mail() function.

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists("email", $_POST)) {

    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "This is the Subject";

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <no-reply@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

    $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Success";
     }else {
        echo "Failed";
     }

}
?>
```

The To and From addresses are valid I just used a placeholder for this post. The message POST variable is a HTML string.

I know that the mail() function has some problems and people recommend something using different add ons like the phpmailer, but I know that has a limit on the amount of emails it can send per day and I wanted to try and avoid that.

My php script sends the email and I successfully get the email but it returns false. Any idea why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395998/1902010 perhaps?

Comment: Side note: phpmailer (and my preference, SwiftMailer) does **not** have a daily limit on emails. You've been misinformed.

Comment: Have you checked what's the value returned by $retval ? I think there might be an type or value problem ! Kindly check and post that result if can !

Comment: Agreed with @ceejayoz ! There isnt any daily limit on emails for phpmailer. In fact it's best

Comment: Depends on your OS and MTA.