# how do I get correct output for this form validation code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My code is executing only `else` statement ... I couldn't find a problem.
When I validated form attribute address with javascript, it is not taking validation from PHP code and taking `else` statement

**expected result**: Thanks for your order

**actual result**: technical issue

```php
<?php
    $toEmail = "herbsoul1@gmail.com";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["name"] . "<". $_POST["email"] .">\r\n";
    $subject="Site Mail from Xtreme-Fatburn";
    $content="Name : ".$_POST["name"]."\n";
    $content=$content."MobileNo : ".$_POST["MobileNo"]."\n";
    $content=$content."Email : ".$_POST["email"]."\n";
    $content=$content."State : ".$_POST["State"]."\n";
    $content=$content."Address : ".$_POST["address"]."\n";
    if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $content, $mailHeaders)) {
        print "Thanks for your order.";
    } else {
        print "Some Technical Issues occured.";
    }
?>
```

background code

```html
<div id="about1" class="container-fluid " style="width:100%;height:580px">
  <div class="row bg">
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:192px;margin-left:0px;">
      <div class="row main">

        <div class="main-login main-center">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label dntr">Your Name</label><span id="userName-info" class="info">*</span>
              <div class="cols-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label dntr">Mobile No</label><span id="userName-info" class="info">*</span>
              <div class="cols-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-mobile-phone" style="font-size:20px"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="MobileNo" id="MobileNo" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your Mobile No" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label dntr">Your Email ID</label><span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
              <div class="cols-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email ID" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label dntr">State</label><span id="userName-info" class="info">*</span>
              <div class="cols-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                    <option>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                    <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
                    <option>Arunachal Prades</option>
                    <option>Assam</option>
                    <option>Bihar</option>
                    <option>Chhattisgarh</option>
                    <option>Chandigarh</option>
                    <option>Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                    <option>Daman and Diu</option>
                    <option selected>Delhi</option>
                    <option>Goa</option>
                    <option>Gujarat</option>
                    <option>Haryana</option>
                    <option>Himachal Pradesh</option>
                    <option>Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                    <option>Jharkhand</option>
                    <option>Karnataka</option>
                    <option>Kerala</option>
                    <option>Lakshadweep</option>
                    <option>Madhya Pradesh</option>
                    <option>Maharashtra</option>
                    <option>Manipur</option>
                    <option>Meghalaya</option>
                    <option>Mizoram</option>
                    <option>Nagaland</option>
                    <option>Odisha</option>
                    <option>Punjab</option>
                    <option>Puducherry</option>
                    <option>Rajasthan</option>
                    <option>Sikkim</option>
                    <option>Tamil Nadu</option>
                    <option>Telangana</option>
                    <option>Tripura</option>
                    <option>Uttarakhand</option>
                    <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
                    <option>West Bengal</option>

                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address" class="cols-sm-2 control-label dntr">Your Address</label><span id="userName-info" class="info">*</span>
              <div class="cols-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your address" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" id="Register" onClick="sendContact();">RUSH MY ORDER</button>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

javascript code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
  .info {
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #FF6600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  function sendContact() {
    var valid;
    valid = validateContact();
    if (valid) {
      var name1 = $("#name").val();
      var MobileNo1 = $("#MobileNo").val();
      var email1 = $("#email").val();
      var state1 = $("#sel1").val();
      var address1 = $("#address").val();
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "sendemail.php",
        data: {
          name: name1,
          MobileNo: MobileNo1,
          email: email1,
          State: state1,
          address: address1
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          //$('#Register').html(data);
          $("#name").val('');
          $("#MobileNo").val('');
          $("#email").val('');
          $("#address").val('');
          //$("#mail-status").html(data);
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {}
      });
    }
  }

  function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;
    if (!$("#name").val()) {
      valid = false;
      alert("Please Enter Your Name");
      return valid;
    }
    if ($("#email").val()) {
      if (!$("#email").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
        valid = false;
        alert("Invalid Email ID");
        return valid;
      }
    }
    if (!$("#MobileNo").val()) {
      valid = false;
      alert("Please Enter Your Mobile Number");
      return valid;
    }
    return valid;
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.openPopup').on('click', function() {
      debugger;
      $(".modal-content").html('');
      var dataURL = $(this).attr('href');
      //$('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
      // $('#dialog-example').modal({show:true});
      //});
      $.get(dataURL, function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $(".modal-content").html(data).foundation("open");
      });

    });
  });

  function isNumber(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 &&
      (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `mail()` is returning false, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786221/mail-returns-false)

Comment: If you requested the page from your browser, with method `GET` that will make all the `$_POST` data  empty.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Can you format your post better?

Answer (score 0):

- For getting the post data, change the button type to submit:
  type="submit"
- Also check the post data before sending mail

Answer (score 0):

If you are working locally in windows In C:\xampp\php in php.ini file you have to check the setup. Find mail function and do the changes as below

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Don’t remove the semi column if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25
```

Remove the semi colons before SMTP and smtp_port and set the SMTP to your smtp server and the port to your smtp port. Your settings should look as follows

```
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
```

And if your configuration is fine, please check the mail spam folder or mail configuration, whether it has some restriction.

OR
Use PHPMailerAutoload.php PHPMailer, that is quiet easy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your "HTML, Javascript & PHP" codes in my Windows XAMPP and after configuring the details in the php.ini & in sendmail.ini files, as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/6905312), I can successfully send the email.